# Usage of going to vs going to go

Tags: tense, usage

> I'm ***going to*** Japan. I already have my plane ticket.

Correct!

> I'm ***going to go*** to Japan. I already have my plane ticket.

Wrong!

I thought there was no difference in meaning between these two sentences, but I was told the second one was wrong because *going* in the second sentence is close to *planning*. Would speakers of standard English agree? Thank you very much.

Comment: In most contexts, your two examples have the same meaning and are completely idiomatic. Who told you that the latter was wrong?

Comment: In *some* contexts, *I'm going to Japan* might mean I'm ***currently*** making that journey. But *I'm **going to go** Japan* can never mean that - to be "going to [do something]" *always* means you ***will do it in the future*** (it never means *be currently doing it*).

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum It's from the lesson training material from the company I'm working with.  I was actually called to answer this similar question: Which one is correct? A.  I'm going to Japan. However, I haven't arranged yet. B. I'm going to go to Japan. However, I haven't arranged yet.    My answer was both are acceptable though I picked the first one. I was told only B is correct.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the answer. But in the given context of the sentence " I'm going to go to Japan. I already have my plane ticket," would you mark this wrong?

Comment: One context in which they **do** differ is if you mean that your travel has begun, so you are currently en route. In that case, “I’m going to Japan” means, “At this moment I am engaged in travel to Japan.” Maybe your plane is over the middle of the ocean. In that case, “I am going to go to Japan” would be flat wrong because it is unambiguously commenting about the future; it means that you **will go**.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Thanks for the example. So just to be clear, you wouldn't mark this wrong either, "I'm going to Japan. However, I haven't arranged yet."?

Comment: I would not mark that wrong.

Comment: In a context where it's *relevant* that you haven't yet made the arrangements, it's more natural to say *I'm going to go to Japan*, because *to be going to do something* usually means ***to intend to** [do it]*. If you've already got your ticket, it's usually more natural to just say you're going, not going to go.

Comment: Why not provide an answer? We are not supposed to answer in comments!

Comment: I gave a formal answer that covers the meanings. If you do not choose it, I will remove it since I went to the trouble...

Comment: If your training material tells you that only one of the examples in your question is "correct", get some different training material! As Lambie's answer and several comments should make clear, *syntactically speaking* it's irrelevant whether you've already got your plane ticket. The only "incorrect" use would be if you said "I'm going to go to Japan" *while actually **en route** to Japan* (because ***to be going to** [do something]* is a ***future tense***, so it doesn't really work for something you're ***currently*** doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to Japan. means: I have the intention of going to Japan **or** that I am on my way to Japan.

He's going to see her. He has the intention of going to see her or he is on his way to seeing her.

The present continuous therefore has two possible meanings.

WHEREAS: I'm **going to go** to Japan. is **a future tense**. You are not going right now. The same is true of: He's going to go see her. He is not seeing her right now.

Comment: Thanks for making an answer. I appreciate it.  But having this context as relevant, "I'm going to go to Japan. I already have my plane ticket" would you mark this wrong?

Comment: @user424874 No, of course not. You can go in the future and have already bought a ticket.

Comment: Jokes aside, assuming the ticket was bought a long time earlier (say, a year or so), **going to go** essentially means planning to go next year.
I don't believe it can ever be considered wrong, but it might sound weird (*"I'm going to go to Japan in an hour"* for example).

Comment: @Christian going to go is a future and a ticket can have been bought at any time in past. The two are not related grammatically and they are both grammatical.

Comment: @Lambie I was reinforcing your point with an example, not arguing against it.